# Query AccountId from LinkedEntityId

Tags: relationships, contentdocumentlink

I would like a list of all files which are concerning to a account record, but my files have only a relation to the contacts. How can I query all files of the account?

The LinkedEntityId is from a contact then I want to know which account the contact belongs to.
Is there a easy way to use Contact.AccountId?

```
SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Title, ContentDocument.createdDate, ContentDocument.Createdby.Name, ContentDocument.FileExtension FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE Contact.AccountId =: currentRecordId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `ContactId` standard field on ContentDocumentLink, but you could use a [semi-join](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm#semi_and_anti), a subquery on Contact in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId, ContentDocument.Title, ContentDocument.createdDate, ContentDocument.Createdby.Name, ContentDocument.FileExtension
FROM ContentDocumentLink
WHERE LinkedEntityId IN (SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId =: currentRecordId)
```